# Postgres: Show sql´s of wal segments

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, write-ahead-logging

I am trying to set up wal archiving for the first time. I did add the folder with correct permissions:

```
backup/wal
```

Then i added these entries to the postgresql.conf:

```
wal_level=archive
archive_mode=on
archive_command = 'test ! -f /backup/wal/%f && cp %p /backup/wal/%f'
```

And made the initial backup successfully. I want to double check what gets written into the wal segments. Is there a way to inspect the sql statements of a given wal file?

Comment: it might be smart to check the postgres log since your database seems to be stuck in a startup. (do you have a filesystem filled up status?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should use edit to clarify your question, not to convert it into an entirely different question.  Just ask a new question if you want to ask a new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect the contents of the WAL segments with `pg_waldump`. However, you won't find any SQL statements there, because that's not how transactions are logged. WAL contains very low-level information that tells what to modify in which data file.

Your `archive_command` will only be good for testing purposes. You shouldn't archive your WAL on the database machine.

Answer (score 2):

WAL tracks the data changes, not the SQL causing those changes.  You can use pg_waldump to parse the WAL, but what it generates is not likely what you want to see.  You can also view the WAL itself with things like `od` or `vim -Rb`.